# Access of Work-Group

Tags: workgroup

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. I have four PCs in "ABCD" work-group. I want access all four PCs from each other. But I don't want some one can access those PCs of "ABCD" workgroup from another work-group.

Comment: Can u give us a more details about your network topology and if u have a domain controller

Answer (score 2):

Consider VLANs on a switch. That will probably be your best bet to keep unwanted traffic from flowing between the two workgroups. A lot of new small business routers are capable of this as well. So, perhaps purchase one with that capability and buy two cheap switches. Plug one switch into LAN port 1 and the other into LAN port 2. Go into the router settings and set LAN port 1 and LAN port 2 on separate VLANS.